# Enter key focus for a JButton in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, key

How to make Enter key focus for a JButton in java swing?

i have done like this

```
btn_Login.registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       System.out.println("enter key pressed");

    }
}, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0,false), txt_Username.WHEN_FOCUSED);
```

but not working

Comment: refer this link http://www.devx.com/DevX/Tip/31605

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want a specific button to be "pressed" if you just press Enter on a certain window.

To do this, you have to set the defaultButton on your RootPane of the current JFrame.

Here is an example:

```
 JButton btn = new JButton();
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();

 frame.getContentPane().add(btn);
 frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btn);
```

That should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all! Here are some notes that I found out to fix the enter problem for the Nimbus Look and fell.

1. The enter key works with linux but not with windows ( Nimbus ).
2. For windows the actual "doClick" of the button is done with space ( Key Char 32 ).
3. It's possible to set the "enter" to do a click, but it must be done AFTER setting your Nimbus Look and Feel.
4. Here is the code that is used in my application.

   ```
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
       //- hack pour que les bouttons qui ont le focus fassent un doClick
       //- lorsque "enter" est taper.  Auparavant, c'etait l'espace qui 
       //- activait le doClick.
       InputMap im = (InputMap)UIManager.get("Button.focusInputMap");
       im.put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "ENTER" ), "pressed" );
       im.put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "released ENTER" ), "released" );
   ```

( Sorry for my french comments ! ).